# Spring OAuth redirect_uri not using https

Tags: oauth, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 1.3.0 application with Spring Security OAuth included as a sort of SSO integration.

The problem is that the application is running in a non-SSL environment with a non-standard port behind a load balancer (F5) that forces SSL and the OAuth provider requires all redirect URLs be registered as https, but the Spring OAuth client (auto-configured with @EnableOAuthSso) will only redirect to the OAuth provider with the following URL...

https://[provider_host]/oauth/authorize?client_id=[redact]***&redirect_uri=http://[application_host]/login***&response_type=code&scope=[redact]&state=IpMYTe

Note that the return redirect_uri is generated as http.  Even though the F5 will force it to https on the way back, our OAuth provider will not allow a non-SSL redirect URI.  How can I configure this?

With the exception of my Spring Data JPA controllers, this is the entirety of the app...

### AppConfig.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryInfo() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fac = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        fac.setDataSource(dataSource);
        fac.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        fac.setPackagesToScan("[redact]");

        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        fac.setJpaProperties(props);

        return fac;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactMngr = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactMngr.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryInfo().getObject());
        return transactMngr;
    }

}
```

### SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig {

}
```

### application.properties

```
server.port=9916
server.contextPath=

server.use-forward-headers=true

security.oauth2.client.clientId=[redact]
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=[redact]
security.oauth2.client.scope=[redact]
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=https://[provider_host]/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=https://[provider_host]/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=https://[provider_host]/oauth/me
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=false

logging.level.org.springframework=TRACE
```

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but instead of wanting to be HTTPS, the URI is always returned to me as HTTPS when I want HTTP. Would you know how to do this same thing but in the opposite direction? I've already applied your answer to the application.properties file with no luck.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After digging manually through the configuration classes I was able to find and add the following, which did the trick...

```
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://[application_host]/login
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://[application_host]/login
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

I'm not convinced there isn't a better way to solve the problem of forcing a HTTPS redirect URL, but this fix worked for me.

Comment: Do you know if there's any published documentation about what those four properties do?

Comment: @Mark No, I found information about these by digging through the Spring properties metadata to see which beans they mapped to.  Unfortunately I didn't track it somewhere.

Comment: This settings saved my life ... thanks to Zack. They are defined in org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.redirect.AbstractRedirectResourceDetails.

Comment: Can you provide full example of this one wtih github repo? Spent so many hours but still stuck with redirect_uri.

Comment: Can the redirect uri use an external URL ?

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This helped putting a legacy (Spring Boot 1.5) behind a reverse proxy (where enabling proxy added headers breaks other things, and you're forced to not include them).

Answer (score 26):

You may need to ensure that your application understands `x-forwarded` headers from your load balancer.

Putting this in my `application.yml` fixed my very similar problem with an application behind an AWS ELB:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    remote-ip-header: x-forwarded-for
    protocol-header: x-forwarded-proto
```

**Edit:** This can be simplified with the more generic configuration:

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

**For Apache Tomcat** use `RemoteIpValve` in `server.xml` (above `AccessLogValve`):

```
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
        protocolHeader="X-Forwarded-Proto" />
```

See also: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html.

Comment: I agree with Carlos, OP, this is the best answer I've found for the latest versions of Spring Security. I'm using  Spring 5.1.9.RELEASE, Spring Security 5.1.6.Release and Spring Boot 2.1.8.RELEASE.

Comment: i'm in AWS behind a ALB.  the accepted answer had no affect.  this answer did it.

Comment: @ImtiazShakilSiddique added info about `RemoteIpValve`. You should be able to use it in Tomcat 6 and above.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer @Nux, I also solved the problem with `RemoteIpValve`

Comment: If you need an explanation and configs for nginx check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929017/4950185

Comment: Note that as of Spring Boot 2.2. you should use `server.forward-headers-strategy=native` instead of `server.use-forward-headers`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126518/how-to-cope-with-x-forwarded-headers-in-spring-boot-2-2-0-spring-web-mvc-behin

Comment: thanks @TillKuhn in my case `server.use-forward-headers` does not work for Spring Boot 2.1.x, `ForwardedHeaderFilter` worked great.

Answer (score 12):

My answer is for people using latest spring version, as the answers suggested above  didnt work for me. I am using Spring Boot 2.3.5.RELEASE.

I had a the same issue, I am using Azure AD for oauth2 authentication. My application runs behind the reverse proxy and redirect uri formed was taking http rather than https.

After reading the document https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.x/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2Client-auth-code-redirect-uri
, I added below line in the application.properties files and it worked for me

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri=https://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}/login/oauth2/code/azure
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a dream. I hard coded the path for each of the providers.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have mentioned the use of oauth I think this will help someone to understand the flow of operation. This answer only applies if you are using a reverse proxy such as NGINX.

**Cause of the problem,**

Your spring boot application is running on the server with a address simlar to http://localhost:8080 . That's what all the spring boot app know about its host. You can inspect this behavior if you check the redirect url in facebook(or other oauth client) error page. It will look something like https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,name,email,verified,is_verified,picture.width(250).height(250),link&redirect_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin%2Ffacebook

*See the redirect_url is wrong.*

So we need to somehow tell the application that it is hosted under this address.

**Quick fix**

If you are only looking to fix Facebook OAuth ( Or other oAuth provider), Adding following lines to client will fix.

```
facebook:
  client:
     preEstablishedRedirectUri: https://yourdomain.com/
     useCurrentUri: false
```

But, this will only fix the issue at hand ( Also not flexible). **But if you need a more concrete solution which is portable**, you need to solve this at the reverse proxy.

Open your nginx configuration for the app and change it reflecting as follows.

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; # Will add the user's ip to the request, some apps need this
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # will forward the protocole i.e. http, https
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port; # Will forward the port 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                    # !Important will forward the host address
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

Okay so now, nginx is sending the information which were previously hidden to the spring boot app. But yet, spring app is not using this information. To tell it to use these information add the following line to the application.yml.

```
server.use-forward-headers = true
```

If you have your reverse proxy in a different node of the same network, you may want to configure the ip of the reverse proxy server with the following. ( replace with your IP)

```
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=192\.65\.210\.55
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I add theses two parameters to force HTTPS in redirect_uri :

```
preEstablishedRedirectUri: https://...
useCurrentUri: false
```

It works : "redirect_uri" is now using HTTPS

Comment: Where did you make this changes? Can you provide more details?

Comment: You have to make this change in the Spring oauth properties. If you are using separate configuration you can use OAuth2RestTemplate and by using a OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails you can setup those properties. I did this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use `spring.oauth2.client.access-token-uri`

configuration parameter changed after 1.3.0.M1

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.3.0-M1-Configuration-Changelog

Comment: "security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri" I believe still functions in this way.

Comment: 0
down vote
How does it handle the redirect after it authenticates. OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter is added by the @@EnableOAuth2Sso so I do not have a way to redirect. The default redirect is "/" (context) and again it uses http. Has anybody made this working successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, I use Spring Boot 3 and I hope this answer helps you

In your Spring Boot application, add following configuration to your **application.properties** file:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=native
```

Next, in your **Nginx** configuration, add the following lines:

```
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

explanation

forward-headers-strategy:
This property specifies how the application should handle forwarded headers, which are headers that may be added by proxy servers like Nginx. In your case, you're using Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of your Spring Boot application

native:
Spring Boot will try to use native methods provided by the underlying server, like Nginx, to extract and handle forwarded headers efficiently. It can lead to better performance and more accurate handling of headers

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
ensures that Nginx passes the original Host header to your Spring Boot application

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
can be useful for your application to determine the actual source of the request

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
When a request passes through several proxy servers, it accumulates a list of IP addresses corresponding to each proxy in the chain

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
The X-Forwarded-Proto header indicates whether the original request was made using HTTP or HTTPS

reference
https://codemasterkimc.tistory.com/644