# Spring Boot OAuth2 https redirect_uri instead of http

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I use Spring Boot OAuth2 and `@EnableOAuth2Client`.  My application runs on HTTPS but when I try to login to Odnoklassniki Social Network it generates following url:

```
https://connect.ok.ru/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://example.com/api/login/ok&response_type=code&state=XXXXXX
```

Is any way to change `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` in this url ?

Comment: Register your application within your social network. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl

Comment: Possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https