# redirect_uri using http instead of https

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm using spring stack (Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE) for creating a site that delegues user authentication/registration to Facebook via OAuth2. When I click the "login with facebook" button I get redirected to Facebook, but Spring Security OAuth2 is creating the redirect_uri parameter using http instead of https. The application uses https and I can't figure out where this "http" is coming from.

So, how can I make Spring create the redirect_uri parameter correctly?

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the original post. It was late and I wanted to have the question posted before going sleep :-)

Well, my application uses Spring Boot 2.0.1.RELEASE, which comes with Spring Security 2.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Security OAuth2 5.0.4.RELEASE. My application uses Facebook for registering and authenticating users. Currently I have a test environment running in AWS (Beanstalk) and using Amazon's SSL certificate.

When I first wrote the post my issue was that the redirect_uri parameter sent by my application (by SS actually) to Facebook had a http prefix, instead of https. This was causing an error in Facebook, which only accepts https redirect urls.

Reading the docs I found the `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.facebook.redirect-uri-template` property, which I set to `https://[my domain]/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`. Now Facebook processes my authentication requests and posts back to my application.

However, with the previous parameter set, now the problem has changed. Now when the Facebook's callback hits my application at AWS I get the following exception (from the logs):

```
2018-04-11 10:51:23 [http-nio-5000-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter - Request is to process authentication
2018-04-11 10:51:23 [http-nio-5000-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider
2018-04-11 10:51:23 [http-nio-5000-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider
2018-04-11 10:51:23 [http-nio-5000-exec-5] DEBUG o.s.s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter] 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:159)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Taking a look at the sources I found that the issue seems to be in the following test in the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider` class:

```
if (!authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri().equals(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())) {
    OAuth2Error oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error(INVALID_REDIRECT_URI_PARAMETER_ERROR_CODE);
    throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString());
}
```

To check why this comparison is failing I checked the requests and responses using Chrome's developer tools. So, this is the call to Facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=[REMOVED]&scope=public_profile%20email&state=[REMOVED]&redirect_uri=https://[REMOVED]/login/oauth2/code/facebook
```

Everything seems to be ok, the redirect_uri parameter is using https as expected and the complete redirect_uri seems correct.

And this is Facebook's callback:

```
https://[REMOVED]/login/oauth2/code/facebook?code=[REMOVED]
```

Once again, everything seems ok. However, SS is rejecting the user authentication because request and response redirect_uris are not matching.

And this is the issue. Any idea of what is going wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: it would be nice if you could share your configuration and properties file. It is hard to guess any thing with this information.

Comment: I posted an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61929017/4950185 in a simlar question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring OAuth redirect\_uri not using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### I faced with exact the same problem but with Google.

Having the following architecture of microservices

```
Google Auth Server


  Zuul Gateway (:8080)
     /   \
    /     \
   /       \
Other      OAuth2Client (:5000)
```

while running at local machine everything works fine, but in AWS Elastic Beanstalk I catch the very same exception.

After debugging, I found out that in my case, when OAuth2Client is behind Zuul proxy (they implemented in separate microservices) I really get different redirect_uri values in the check inside `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider`:

```
if (!authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri().equals(authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri())) {
    OAuth2Error oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error(INVALID_REDIRECT_URI_PARAMETER_ERROR_CODE);
    throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error, oauth2Error.toString());
}
```

So in my case in AWS I have following values:

```
authorizationResponse.getRedirectUri()
http://[INNER_AWS_ESB_IP]:5000/auth/login/oauth2/code/google

authorizationRequest.getRedirectUri()
https://[MY_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME]/auth/login/oauth2/code/google
```

where `[INNER_AWS_ESB_IP]` is an IP address of inner network in AWS Elastic Beanstalk and `[MY_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME]` is a domain name of my project, which is hardcoded in `application.yml` as `redirect-uri-template` parameter.

I have the following config in `application.yml` of my **OAuth2Client** microservice

```
server:
  port: 5000
  servlet:
     contextPath: /auth
  use-forward-headers: true

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resource:
        filter-order: 3
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id:  [REMOVED]
            client-secret: [REMOVED]
            redirect-uri-template: ${MY_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME:http://localhost:8080}/auth/login/oauth2/code/google
            scope: profile,email
```

Loreno, what kind of architecture do you have? Can you share your config?

### UPDATE

Seems that problem is connected directly with implementation of Spring Security Oauth2 Client in version science 5.0

Problem can be reproduced, if launch Zuul Gateway microservice on some separate virtual machine and other microservices should be launched at local machine ☝️ So Google should be called from the browser on VM.

**The solution** which helps me to avoid this problem is to add custom `Filter` with custom `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which can override method and return "right" URL to satisfy the check in `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java:115`

1. In the `application.yml` of the Oauth2 client

   `myCloudPath: ${MY_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME:http://localhost:8080}`
2. In the `SecurityConfig`

   ```
   @Value("${myCloudPath}")
   private String myCloudPath;

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.
            addFilterBefore(new MyCustomFilter(myCloudPath), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class).
            ...
   ```
3. Filter

   ```
   public class MyCustomFilter implements Filter {

       private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyCustomFilter.class);
       private String myCloudPath;


       public MyCustomFilter(String myCloudPath) {
           this.myCloudPath= myCloudPath;
       }

       @Override
       public void init(FilterConfig filterConfiguration) throws ServletException {
           logger.info("MyCustomFilter init");
       }

       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
               throws IOException, ServletException {

           request = new MyHttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request, myCloudPath);

           chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }

       @Override
       public void destroy() {
           logger.info("MyCustomFilter destroy");
       }
   }
   ```
4. HttpServletRequestWrapper

   ```
   public class MyHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

       public final String redirectUrl;

       public MyHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String myCloudPath) {
           super(request);
           this.redirectUrl = myCloudPath + request.getRequestURI();
       }

       @Override
       public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
           return new StringBuffer(redirectUrl);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry for the late response. The problem was the SSL offloading at AWS' environment. The Facebook callback is made using https but, due to the Elastic Load Balancer SSL offloading, the request that actually hits my application is http, instead of https. Including `use-forward-headers: true` in my configuration solved the problem.

Comment: @Andrew how did you debug redirect uri in authorizationRequest and authorizationResponse ?

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same error when I m setting up a Spring Boot application to authenticate users using Facebook OAuth2 implementation. Nginx (functions as reverse proxy) is configured to front the web app and also to offload the SSL cert.

Initially, I tried to customize the property: `redirect-uri-template` so that the redirect uri can be hard-coded with `https://{domain}/login/oauth2/code/facebook` (this is because Facebook only accepts HTTPS protocol for valid OAuth Redirect URI). It didnt work as I encountered the same error: `OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter]`

Then, I found the proposed solution in [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5270), which works for me. So, it is basically to set the OAuth2 Login Application with `server.use-forward-headers=true` and remove the customized property: `redirect-uri-template`.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Just to sum up, here in the official [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server)

Comment: @mengjiann how did you debug which exactly redirectUri you received?

Comment: In my case, I also had to add this to my nginx config:        
`proxy_set_header        Host $host;`
`proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;`
`proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`
`proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`

Comment: Great man! it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

We faced the same issue while running in OpenShift and authenticating against Microsoft Azure. Filtering seemed like hacking, the `*.redirect-uri-template` properties are now deprecated, and after returning from Azure the outgoing and incoming redirect URIs did not match.

After much searching, this simple entry in `application.properties` solved the issue:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem and nothing worked after trying all solutions available on google and stack overflow. This resolved the problem for me:

1. I upgraded the Spring-boot version to "2.3.1.RELEASE" and rebuilt the application. Then added this property in application.yml (talking about google here but i think it will work for facebook, okta and other identity provider platforms) :

---

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client: 
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: 'your google client id'
            clientSecret: 'your google client secret'
            redirect-uri: https://www.yourdomain.com/login/oauth2/code/google # important
```

Defining redirect-uri , did the work and that was only possible if you are working on a spring-boot 2.3.x and above release.
Don't waste your time on "redirect-uri-template" as you will be facing problem when google redirects the user-agent back to your application. Spring will still be authenticating the redirect-uri internally.

2. If you are working behind a reverse proxy (may be nginx) the this should be your server configuration :

   ```
    location / {
        absolute_redirect off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
   ```

These settings on ngnix will make sure that Spring gets requests header which are coming in the request. I was using tomcat on port 8080 hence defined this in proxy_pass. You can change this for your application.

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For me works this.
I have set

```
redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
```

and wrote custom filter which chnge http to https

```
@Slf4j
public class LinkedInRewriteFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final String GET_PROTOCOL = "://.*";
private static final String LINKED_IN = "linkedin";
private static final String HTTPS = "https";

@Value("${base-url}")
private String baseUrl;

@Value("${server.port}")
private int serverPort;

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (request.getRequestURL().toString().contains(LINKED_IN)) {
        request = new LinkedInHttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}

public class LinkedInHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public LinkedInHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getScheme() {
        return baseUrl.replaceFirst(GET_PROTOCOL, StringUtils.EMPTY);
    }

    @Override
    public int getServerPort() {
        return HTTPS.equals(getScheme()) ? 443 : serverPort;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Jakub!
How did you debug that you receive redirectUri with http instead of https ?

Comment: Actually yes. Our apps use HTTP but we operate behind Apache (443) 
So I installed apache locally and then debug and found out UriComponentsBuilder set HTTP or https based on which your application use. But I find out that you can set properties like X-Forwarded-SSL or similar to change this behavior but I did not try. You can check UriComponentsBuilder 
In my case OAuth client uses `UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(request))

Comment: But if you want to use my solution you should set LinkedIn the filter like 
  `.addFilterBefore(linkedInRewriteFilter(), OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class)`

Probably it is possible to solve it by settling right properties to change UriComponentsBuilder behavior but you now for me it is working and have no time ...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to do these:

**Step 1:** Change your config file

If using application.properties

```
server.port=8081
server.use-forward-headers: true
```

If using yml

```
server:
port: 8081
use-forward-headers : true
```

**Step 2:** Update proxy

If using httpd

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
```

If using nginx

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; # Will add the user's ip to the request, some apps need this
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # will forward the protocole i.e. http, https
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port; # Will forward the port 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                    # !Important will forward the host address
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
}
```

**Step 3:** Restart server and test

Answer (score 0):

I think the new version of Spring Security just added new support for `.redirect-uri` replacing `.redirect-uri-template`.

### Dependencies

I am using
`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.2.RELEASE`,`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.3.2.RELEASE`,`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.3.2.RELEASE`.

### Configuration File, e.g., `.properties`

In the configuration file, I could specify:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=https://example.com/api/login/oauth2/code/google
```

> Note that I did not use `.redirect-uri-template`

### OAuth2 Flow

Then, Spring OAuth2 guides requests to the Google server with the URI like:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?response_type=...&
redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2Flogin%2Foauth2%2Fcode%2Fgoogle
```

> Note that `redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com` has been encoded, where `https://` protocol is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using container apps or web apps contained over Linux, refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189883/how-to-set-redirect-uri-protocol-to-https-in-azure-web-apps). It could be caused by authentication redirecting to provider handle that's not served over HTTPS.