# Session cookie not being set on server

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I changed OAuth2 Login form frontend to backend implementation. OAuth2Login is setup using spring security configuration.
Everything worked in local machine.

But on server it doesn't create Session Cookie anymore. Which, I guess, creates the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:165) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't entirely accurate that the session cookie wasn't being set. I think I looked it wrongly in chrome when I was looking it in production. But the cookie was seemed to be reset.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            redirectUri: https://<youurl>/login/oauth2/code/google
```

When I added this it created new problem:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter] 
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:132) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5
.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:186)
```

This is because `redirectUri` is HTTPS but google always returns HTTP
So I ended up adding reading a [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477911/1690081) and added a `OncePerRequestFilter` to my project. Since it's google that is sending this over HTTP they must be thinking it's secure. Couldn't find any way to make google send it over HTTPS