# Redirect_Uri use http instead of https with Spring social Facebook Login on Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, heroku, spring-security, spring-social-facebook

This is Spring MVC application and host on Heroku which has valid ssl certificate.

When I click on the following link from the spring mvc web application

```
https://www.website.com/auth/facebook
```

It redirects to this link

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567890&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook&scope=email&state=62b62bad-f8c8-44a3-bacf-a13ce12dfcce
```

In this, redirect_uri takes *http* instead *https*. How to forced **https** to redirect_uri?

I have followed the solution mentioned in this question 
[Spring OAuth redirect_uri not using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https)

and created following file but it didn't work.

The application.propeties file contains

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For
server.tomcat.protocol-header=X-Forwarded-Proto
server.use-forward-headers=true

security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://www.website.com/login
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://www.website.com/login
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this issue?

Comment: its 2021. why does facebook do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **.net core** application then in **Configure**  Method at **Startup.cs** file add the following line of It should be work.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "https")
                {
                    context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                }
                return next();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Facebook Developer, Below Products tab go to Facebook login
[image: facebook login]

Make sur **Enfore https** is set to yes

[image: https]

Then in **valid oauth reidrect url** add https urls

[image: valid oauth urls]

Change your site Url to https:

[image: Basic settings]

[image: Website]
and I am really surprised how Facebook redirects you to http! 
From 1st may all the redirects should redirected to https. Even in your **localhost**, you need to create a self-signed certificate to get facebook login working.

Comment: Everything is working fine on localhost. The problem is when site is host on Heroku

Comment: Did you change valid oauth redirect urls to your site and forec https in facebook?

Comment: Yes. Facebook force https by default now.

Comment: But your valid Oauth uris, are they include https? Another thing to do is to check Website panel inside **Basic settings**. See above

Comment: Who generates this url? redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook&scope=email&state=62b62bad-f8c8-44a3-bacf-a13ce12dfcce


Is it generated by Facebook or is it generated by Spring Social plugin?

Comment: Spring security OAuth2 login redirects to the URL of the provider which is Facebook in this case, and it provides a Redirect_URL as a request parameter so that Facebook knows where to send the user to after they finish the authentication process at Facebook.   
   
• So Spring Security is generating the Redirect_URL   
• As per Facebook's requirements is must be HTTPS, and it needs to be configured in the Valid OAuth Redirect URLs in Facebook OAuth app configuration

Comment: @MohamedRagab someone comment on the github issue regarding it. I haven't try. Let me know if work for you https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/issues/245#issuecomment-407076229

Comment: @Keyul this solution worked for me https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5631

Comment: @MohamedRagab Awesome. Can you post the complete solution as an answer to this question? It will be useful to others.