# oAuth2 redirect with http protocol instead of https protocal

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

According to my deployment architecture oAuth2 server run with http protocol. Client request to F5 switch using https protocol, and F5 switch will forward this call to oAuth2 with http protocol. That is ok and I get login page from oAuth2 server. But problem is when perform login oAuth2 redirect with http protocol, where it should be https protocol.

For example:
Goto login page url is:
Request URL: https://192.144.80.117:10900/authentication-service-provider-1.0/login

Result: Get login page

provide login info (wrong credential for testing purpose) and click submit.
It should return: **https://192.144.80.117:10900/authentication-service-provider-1.0/login?error**

But it return: **http://192.144.80.117:10900/authentication-service-provider-1.0/login?error**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was able to solve it by setting

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

in my applications.yml.

For reference:

[Stackoverflow: Spring OAuth redirect_uri not using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https)

[SpringBoot Docs: How to use Tomcat behind a proxy server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
but I have already used this (**server.use-forward-headers=true**) property in application.properties file. Result same. Have any another idea !

Comment: I have changed my architecture little bit. oAuth2 server start with https mode. But it is workaround.