# Spring boot, Oauth Authorization callback URL - Dev and Production setup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth

In springboot , I have OAuth support for common social auth providers, for example **github**

In github you need to provide authorization callback url:

[image]

So i have provided https://localhost:443/login/oauth2/code/github

This works fine on DEV, Localhost . Bud when it comes to my dockerized application running on cloud, this wont work, Now I will change this for real url so in production it works, bud how do I continue on testing / developing application locally? My OAuth wont work properly when i set it on github to prod!

**What is a common solution to this problem? Should i have some kind of redirect and look for requests comming to PROD_URL AND REDIRECT TO DEV_URL?**

Is there some better solution?
Maybe a host file change from my prod url to localhost ? :D (sounds dirty)

Comment: Hi. Just like we have application environment properties,  we can have multiple github ( any OAUTH server ) configurations dedicated to local/UAT/...etc.. In the application ( OAUTH client application ) manage the client properties based on deployment environment ?

Comment: I think you can provide the callback URL directly in the params `/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=CALLBACK_URL` so it should override the specified above one.

Comment: @StanislavL Currently I use default spring settings for all of this, Where would i define this url ? I dont think i call explicitly anything like this as far as i remember.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https

Comment: I looked at it bud not sure about how to do this . Still, not sure if that is related to what i need

Comment: Can't you use application.yml profiles for dev and prod property and using @Value annotation it automatically picks based on the active profile.

Comment: On github i have only one url field i can use, one value, how would me changing something locally, change what github calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was actually stupid question, the easy solution is just create new app for those social networks, one for dev, one for prod, and then in dev profile you use dev keys and for prod .... 
No need to overcomplicate it.