# spring security - sending http request instead of https

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, pingfederate

We are facing the below issues with spring security; spring boot version is 2.3.1 and the component is behind the **nginx**. The LB url to nginx is **Https** and from nginx to other components are **HTTP**.

The request to pingfed from the spring security component is going as http instead of https:

Application yml. The component is sending the redirect_url as http instead of https, even if we hit https://company/valid:

So, have hardcoded {baseUrl} with https but could see the below issue on browser 'was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://company/auth-service/oauth2/authorization/gateway'

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: pingFed
            client-id: ClientAPP
            client-secret: AP123XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: openid,profile,ClientAPP
            client-authentication-method: basic
        provider:
          pingFed:
            authorization-uri: https://XXX/as/authorization.oauth2
            token-uri: https://XXXX/as/token.oauth2
            user-info-uri: https://XXXX/idp/userinfo.openid
            user-name-attribute: xxxx
            jwk-set-uri: https://XXXX/pf/JWKS
```

And this is my WebSecurityConfigurator. If we uncomment the line:
and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure(). It says ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers("/login/**", "/oauth2/**")
                   .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/valid","/user/me")
                    .authenticated()
                //.and().requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
                .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                        .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                        .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .and()
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .oidcUserService(customOidcUserService);
```

And this is servlet container Bean

```
 @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        //Create a new remoteipvalve
        RemoteIpValve remoteIpValve = new RemoteIpValve();
        //The following values should correspond to the header header of nginx
        remoteIpValve.setRemoteIpHeader("x-forwarded-for");
        remoteIpValve.setProtocolHeader("x-forwarded-proto");
        remoteIpValve.setProtocolHeaderHttpsValue("https");
        //Add a valve for Tomcat
        tomcat.addEngineValves(remoteIpValve);
        return tomcat;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring OAuth redirect\_uri not using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https)

Comment: I don't understand your last two comments. Did you read all answers? You have to configure `https://...` instead of `{baseUrl}`.

Comment: We have 2 issues here  1) {baseUrl} is not redirecting to https, we have hardcoded for now.   2)  When we call this endpoint from client app 'React', we could see the error  on  console  'was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint'     because its internally calling the gateway url  as  http://company/auth-service/oauth2/authorization/gateway

Comment: What endpoint do you call from your React app? Who  is internally calling the gateway URL? Your React app? What error do you get? It is no error to use HTTP instead HTTPS.

Comment: 1) We have an API than authenticate and gives token; say htt://portal/auth-service/valid
2) On load of react app with https, the above api is being called to get the code. So, here its erroring with message  'was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint'.

Comment: What is `htt://portal/auth-service/valid`? React should call `https://XXX/as/authorization.oauth2`. After login, React should get the access token. Both React and authorization server is called by HTTPS. You shouldn't get any error.